# Multiplicações contidas em textos

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Como fazer as multiplicações contidas em um campo `varchar`? (para obter a área, no caso)

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                     DESCRIÇÃO                        |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|Chapa Térmica 605x745 Speed Chemfree                  |
|Chapa Térmica 665 X 910 Ryobi Fuji                    |
|Chapa Convencional P 4001 605x745 Speed IBF           |
|Chapa Térmica 665 X 910 X 030 sem Processo Ryobii IBF |
|Chapa Térmica 800x1030 Komori Chemfree                |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Buscando uma solução alternativa, encontrei uma campo com o tipo de um código para as chapas, o qual contém as dimensões das mesmas:

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|     CODE     |                    DESCRIPTION                       |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| T605745SPCHE | Chapa Térmica 605x745 Speed Chemfree                 |
| T665910RYJUF | Chapa Térmica 665 X 910 Ryobi Fuji                   |
| C605745SPIBF | Chapa Convencional P 4001 605x745 Speed IBF          |
| T665910RYIBF | Chapa Térmica 665 X 910 X 030 sem Processo Ryobii IBF|
| T8001030KBF  | Chapa Térmica 800x1030 Komori Chemfree               |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Creio que meu único problemas agora é como tratar os códigos com 6 ou 7 números a serem multiplicados. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei em qual linguagem está trabalhando então vou tentar ser genérico na resposta:

Comece separando as linhas, e em casa linha utilize uma expressão regular para reconhecer o formato, como por exemplo:

```
\b[0-9]\+x[0-9]\+
```

Essa é uma expressão regular do tipo sed, pode ler mais em

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

A expressão que escrevi diz o seguinte: obténha uma expressão iniciada por um espaço em branco (\b) seguido de um ou mais dígitos ([0-9]+), seguida de um x, e em seguida de um ou mais dígitos.

Pode então separá-las com um split no símbolo x, ou seja, separe em dois elementos, o anterior e o posterior ao x, daí os converta a números e simplesmente vai ter a área calculada.

Comment: Obrigado @AndréClaudinho. A Linguagem que estou usando é MSSQL 2008, está identificada na `TAG`. Consegui um resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Com essa nova coluna, as coisas ficaram bem mais fáceis. Fiz o seguinte:

```
'Area' = (CONVERT(decimal,SUBSTRING(table.CodItem,2,3))*

        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(table.CodItem,8,1) LIKE '[0-9]' THEN
            CONVERT(decimal,SUBSTRING(table.CodItem,5,4)) ELSE
            CONVERT(decimal,SUBSTRING(table.CodItem,5,3)) END)/1000000
```

A função `CONVERT` e a divisão por `/1000000` eu utilizei apenas para conversão de mm² para m². Obrigado!